# jQuery Mobile 1.4 removing previous page from dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

With jQuery Mobile, up until v1., you could remove the page the user was leaving from the dom with something like:

```
$('#Page').live('pagehide', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

However the Pagecontainer Widget is the proper way of handling things like this from jQM 1.4 and going forward. My issue is, I cannot recreate this action with jQM 1.4.

I have tried

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.prevPage).remove();     
});
```

and many similar variations, using pagecontainerhide, pagecontainerbeforeshow etc but i have had no success. The .live('pagehide') version was called within the page the user was leaving, making things a little more accessable, whereas pagecontainerhide is not called from within that "page".

The main issue with this that is killing me is that I am using a responsive calendar (see: http://www.vissit.com/jquery-event-calendar-plugin-english-version) and the first time you goto the page the calendar is on, it works fine, but when you navigate away from that page and return to it later, some parts of the page are duplication because of the js in the eventcalendar plugin. Also, every page after you leave the calender has a JS error also. I just want to remove this page from the dom and do proper cleanup so that this doesn't happen.

As a side note I am open to using a different calendar plugin as well. I need it to be responsive and have a "month" view like the calendar plugin above. I also need to have events when the users clicks/touches on a day within that month. I like this one but the only drawback is that its not completely full screen. I would love to find a good full screen calendar to mimic a native app (like how the month view of google calendar looks on android)

Comment: Note that removing page from DOM doesn't remove it from URL history. If you hit back button, you'll be directed to previous page that is removed, so you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with the latest JQM 1.4.4 and am encountering this as well.

```
$( document ).on( 'mobileinit', function () {

  //this doesn't work
  $(':mobile-pagecontainer').on( 'pagecontainershow', function( event, ui ) {
    ui.prevPage.remove();     
  });

  //this doesn't work either
  $('body').on( 'pagecontainershow', function( event, ui ) {
    ui.prevPage.remove();     
  });

  //this is the only thing that worked for me
  $(document).on( 'pagecontainershow', function( event, ui ) {
    ui.prevPage.remove(); 

    //this way of removing content (on pageshow or pagehide) no
    //longer works reliably for me either. I see DOM nodes being
    //generated, but nothing cleaning up
    //$( event.currentTarget ).remove();     
  });
});
```

good luck Program!

Answer (score 0):

ui.prevPage is already a jQuery collection object. so try:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    ui.prevPage.remove();     
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but unfortunately it did not help

Comment: You can also try $("body").on(... instead of $(":mobile-pagecontainer").on(..., I tried it in a fiddle and it works for me

Comment: I don't think the condition is being hit because if I throw a console log in there, it does not display. The following code is in my head tag in my header template, so it should exist on every page and it never logs.

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('aa');
        ui.prevPage.remove();
    });
    </script>`